# Generic type conversion in generic method

Tags: c#, prism-4

I have the following classes (some of them are in the PRISM framework and cannot be changed):

```
public abstract class NetworkEventBase<T> : CompositePresentationEvent<T> where T : NetworkEventPayload { }
public class NetworkEventPayload { }
public class TestEvent : NetworkEventBase<TestPayload> { }
public class TestPayload : NetworkEventPayload { }

// the following classes are PRISM classes:
public class CompositePresentationEvent<TPayload> : EventBase { }
public abstract class EventBase { }
```

Now I need to convert an instance of TestEvent to its base class NetworkEventBase inside a decorator for IEventAggregator. IEventAggregator looks like:

```
public interface IEventAggregator
{
    TEventType GetEvent<TEventType>() where TEventType : EventBase, new();
}
```

Now in my decorator I try to convert like this:

```
public class MessageBusAdapterInjectorDecorator : IEventAggregator {
    ...

    public TEventType GetEvent<TEventType>() where TEventType : EventBase, new()
    {
        var aggregatedEvent = this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<TEventType>();
        var networkEvent = aggregatedEvent as NetworkEventBase<NetworkEventPayload>;

        if (networkEvent != null)
        {
            networkEvent.MessageBusAdapter = this.messageBusAdapter;
        }

        return aggregatedEvent;
    }
}
```

However, networkEvent is always null, even when the runtime type of aggregatedEvent is TestEvent.

Comment: Please edit sample so it is clear where `networkEvent` coming from.

Comment: The NSA have published a framework for PRISM? scnr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to hope that the ***class*** called `NetworkEventBase<T>` would be covariant in `T`. But generic classes can't be covariant in C# (generic interfaces can).

See other threads on this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have now created an interface that defines a method to inject the IMessageBusAdapter into the event.